# Use ItExpr.IsNull<TValue> rather than a null argument value, as it prevents proper method lookup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write a unit test where I need to set up a protected method. I am using Moq for this setup.

```
_innerHandler.Protected()
             .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
             .ReturnsAsync(responseMessage);
```

When this line executes, it throws the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Use `ItExpr.IsNull<TValue>` rather than a
>   null argument value, as it prevents proper method lookup.

When I change it to use `ItExpr.IsNull<TValue>`, it does allow the test to execute. However, it is of course missing the setup I wanted to configure.

What do I need to do in order to set up a protected method using `It.IsAny<TValue>`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

When setting up an `IProtectedMock`, you should use `Moq.Protected.ItExpr` instead of `Moq.It`.

Here is the corrected implementation of what I was trying to do in my question:

```
_innerHandler.Protected()
             .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
             .ReturnsAsync(responseMessage);
```